# SQL how to make a query to calculate percentage average of variables of survey in form

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm in a dying need for help. I'm absolutely no good in Access but I've taken a survey where I got 100 responses. I converted this from Excel to Acces.
Now, I've created a form where I've set checkboxes for each answers (see image 1)

So what I want to create is when I select some checkboxes of answers, and I'll click "Filteren" it shows next to the answers what the average percentage is of those answers that are checked.

Now, what I'm struggling with is the query, I have absolutely no clue how to start this.
I do have another table called "resultaten" (results) which would show the results of the checked answers, and I know I need to make a query from this table. (image 2)

So I want to create a query per answer that calculates the average but I have absolutely no clue where to start

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial. Browse for this, plenty are available.

Comment: This might be a good starting point for learning SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ It also shows the differences in SQL for Access, MS SQL, or other "dialects". How to get the average is shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp